# Change URI format during harmonization

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am currently working on MarkLogic using Data Hub.

Is there a way you can change a document's URI during harmonization before it gets written to the Final Database?

Current URI Format after Load:

```
/Entity/123456.xml
```

Desired URI Format after Harmonization

```
/Entity/Location/123456.xml
```

where     `Entity` is a constant value, `Location` is a dynamic variable

I saw one related [article](http://developer.marklogic.com/recipe/move-a-document) but it changes the URI if the document is already in the database. I am thinking of doing it during harmonization before the document is written in the FINAL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `writer.xqy` you can write your first line as-

```
let $newuri:="Entity"||($Location)||"123456.xml" (: Or use fn:concat() :)
```

At the last line of `writer.xqy` where you will be using `xdmp:document-insert` just change the `$id` to `$newuri`.

Hope That Helps !